# Why does this Regex match even though it should fail?

Tags: regex, nginx, pcre

I want to extract the first instance of the message ID when a URL is in the form "msgID" or "msg=ID" but not when there are any other characters between "msg" and "ID"

Test strings that should give me the message ID:

```
/forum/index.php/topic,101126.msg3826887.html#msg3826887
/forum/index.php?topic=101126.msg3826887#msg3826887
/forum/index.php?msg=3826887
```

Test strings that should fail:

```
/forum/index.php?msgrad3826887
/forum/index.php?msg,3826887
```

Here's my regex:

`forum\/index.php.+?msg=?([0-9]*)`

However, when I test this in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) or [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/), they show the regex successfully matching all of these strings.

The tests that should fail don't give any result for the capture group, but otherwise appear to match successfully.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix my regex?

Comment: Where are you using this in? RewriteRule? PHP code?

Comment: Is the `.+?` causing it to look up any combination of non-space characters one or more times?

Comment: @nhahtdh Nginx rewrite rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex matches the invalid strings because the ID is optional: `[0-9]*` can match an empty string.

Simply replace the `*` with a `+` to require at least one digit.

Here's an improved version BTW:

```
forum\/index\.php.+?\bmsg=?(\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB5wG0/1)

You should have escaped the `.`. I also added `\b` just before `msg` to ensure `msg` is not part of a longer word. Note that escaping `/` is not required in the regex sense, but your language/tool may require it.

Comment: I'd never seen the `\b` switch before, thx for sharing that improvement

Comment: @Jeff it's a zero-width assertion, roughly equivalent to `(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))`. It ensures that the position where it appears is a word boundary (it considers a character as being part of a word if it's matched by `\w`).